# How to put the content of my webView under the safe area, and way the space around the notch is transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a simple app that shows a web view for different websites, and the problem is the content of the webview doesn't respect the safe area, and the space surrounding the notch is clear. Why?
Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView :  WKWebView!
    var progressView : UIProgressView!
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Open", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(openTapped))
        
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
        progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
        progressView.sizeToFit()
        let progressButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: progressView)
        toolbarItems = [progressButton,spacer,refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress),options: .new, context: nil)
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        
       
    }
    
    @objc func openTapped() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Open...", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "apple.com", style: .default,handler: openPage))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "theverge.com", style: .default,handler: openPage))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel))
        ac.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        present(ac,animated: true )
        
    }
    
    func openPage(action: UIAlertAction){
        guard let actionTitle = action.title else {return}
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://" + actionTitle) else {return}
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        
    }
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            progressView!.progress = Float(webView!.estimatedProgress)
        }
    }


}
```

I have tried to add a margin on top, but it didn't work, and I don't think this is the right way to fix the problem
I am new to IOS Dev. Can you please tell me how to fix this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the controller's view as the web view.

Instead, add the web view as a `subview` and use auto-layout constraints to respect the safe area:

```
var webView :  WKWebView!
var progressView : UIProgressView!

// no no no
//override func loadView() {
//  webView = WKWebView()
//  webView.navigationDelegate = self
//  view = webView
//}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Open", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(openTapped))
    
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
    progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    progressView.sizeToFit()
    let progressButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: progressView)
    toolbarItems = [progressButton,spacer,refresh]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    
    // create web view here
    webView = WKWebView()
    
    // add it to the view
    view.addSubview(webView)
    
    // use auto-layout
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // constrain web view to all 4 sides of the Safe Area
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        
    ])
    
    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress),options: .new, context: nil)
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    
}
```